# HTML Form won't submit after validaiton with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have questions regarding form submitting in HTML with Javascript.

My Javascript is as follows:

```
function validateForm() {
        var a= document.forms["myForm"]["pname"].value;
        var b = document.forms["myForm"]["pemail"].value;
        var c = document.forms["myForm"]["pdob"].value;
        var d = document.forms["myForm"]["unit of choice"].value;
        var els = document.forms["myForm"].elements["Issue[]"];
        var f = document.forms["myForm"]["description"].value;
        var g = document.forms["myForm"]["pdatee"].value;
        var h = document.forms["myForm"]["ptimee"].value;

        var isValid = false;
        for (i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
        if (els[i].checked) {
            isValid = true;
            }
        }


        if (a == null || a == "") {
            alert("Your name cannot be blank");
            }
        if (b == null || b == "") {
            alert("Enter a valid email address.");
            }
        if (c == null || c == "") {
            alert("Enter a valid Date of Birth. (dd/mm/yyyy)");
            }
        if (d == null || d == "") {
            alert("Unit and Tutor have to be selected.");
            }

        if (!isValid) {
            alert("Must select an Issue.");
            }

        if (f == null || f == "") {
            alert("Must fill in a description.");
            }

        if (f == null || f == "") {
            alert("Must fill in a description.");
            }
        if (g == null || g == "") {
            alert("Preferred date must follow the format set.");
            }
        if (h == null || h == "") {
            alert("Preferred time must follow the format set.");
            }

        return false;


    }
```

And this is my form with its attributes in HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="confirm.html" novalidate="novalidate" >
```

What happens is that when I click the Submit button after filling in all the requirements(so everything does not return false) , the form won't submit itself.

After reading around regarding return false, I tried adding else{ return true; } but all it does is submit my form without validation at all.

What do I do to make it work with only Javascript and/or HTML? Thank you!

Comment: because of this `return false;` in your function `validateForm` at the last

Comment: Why are you setting `onsubmit` on you `form` element as `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`? It should be `validateForm`. otherwise your `return validateForm` will return `undefined` or in your case `false` which will prevent form submission.

Comment: Teemu, I'm sorry, its Javascript. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the submission function, you are returning:

```
    return false;
}
```

No matter if the validation was successful or not. This prevents the form from submitting. Make sure you are using `return true` here and correctly validate using a flag and then if the flag is `true`, `return false`.

You have already a flag `isValid`. Replace the above line with:

```
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed I had to return false; to let the alert pop up **and** not submit the form but it turns out that wasn't the case

Comment: @Raph Thanks man. You made my day by accepting the answer! Wish you best! ☺

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your inputs have passed your tests.
You can do that by using your var `isValid`.

All you need to do is set `isValid` to `false` if one of your conditions was not met, and then return `isValid`.

```
function validateForm() {
    var a= document.forms["myForm"]["pname"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myForm"]["pemail"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myForm"]["pdob"].value;
    var d = document.forms["myForm"]["unit of choice"].value;
    var els = document.forms["myForm"].elements["Issue[]"];
    var f = document.forms["myForm"]["description"].value;
    var g = document.forms["myForm"]["pdatee"].value;
    var h = document.forms["myForm"]["ptimee"].value;

    var isValid = false;
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    if (els[i].checked) {
        isValid = true;
        }
    }


    if (a == null || a == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Your name cannot be blank");
        }
    if (b == null || b == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Enter a valid email address.");
        }
    if (c == null || c == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Enter a valid Date of Birth. (dd/mm/yyyy)");
        }
    if (d == null || d == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Unit and Tutor have to be selected.");
        }

    if (!isValid) {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Must select an Issue.");
        }

    if (f == null || f == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Must fill in a description.");
        }

    if (f == null || f == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Must fill in a description.");
        }
    if (g == null || g == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Preferred date must follow the format set.");
        }
    if (h == null || h == "") {
        isValid=false;
        alert("Preferred time must follow the format set.");
        }

    return isValid;


}
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed I had to return false; to let the alert pop up and not submit the form but it turns out that wasn't the case.